# I have several layers of drawings on my panel

Tags: c#, winforms, panel, paint

I created a panel and I put text on it with DrawString and DrawRectangle. To Paint the panel I use the Paint event and the Invalidate method but when Invalidate is called, I have the following result (with back color transparent) :[My panel with drawstring](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WujYQ.png)

As you can see, the text is drawn but what is behind it does not disappear as if Invalidate was half doing his job.

I have set DoubleBuffered to true and I tried Graphics.Clear but no success.

Please someone can help me ?

There is the code :

```
            int x = 0;
        int y = arrowUpHeight;
        int traceIndex = 0;
        lock (_lockDraw)
        {
            while (y < Height)
            {
                rect = new Rectangle(x, y, Width, 20);
                r = new Rectangle(x, y, rect.Width + 1, rect.Height + 1);
                bufferGraphics.SetClip(r);

                if (traceIndex < traceList.Count)
                {
                    if (traceIndex < numberOfTraces)
                    {
                        Line data = traceList[traceIndex];
                        if (traceIndex % 2 == 0)
                        {
                            bufferGraphics.FillRectangle(brushEven, rect);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            bufferGraphics.FillRectangle(brushOdd, rect);
                        }
                        if (y < mousePositionY && mousePositionY < y + 20)
                        {
                            traceSelected = true;
                            traceList[traceIndex].Selected = true;
                            listLinesVisible[traceIndex].Selected = true;
                            listLines[listLines.IndexOf(traceList[traceIndex])].Selected = true;
                            indexRightClick = traceIndex;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (listLines.IndexOf(traceList[traceIndex]) < listLines.Count && listLines.IndexOf(traceList[traceIndex]) >= 0)
                            {
                                traceList[traceIndex].Selected = false;
                                listLinesVisible[traceIndex].Selected = false;
                                listLines[listLines.IndexOf(traceList[traceIndex])].Selected = false;
                            }
                        }
                        if (traceList[traceIndex].Message.ToUpper().Contains(textBoxRUISearch.MyTextBox.Text.ToUpper()) && textBoxRUISearch.MyTextBox.Text != String.Empty)
                        {
                            bufferGraphics.FillRectangle(searchBrush, rect);
                        }
                        if (traceList[traceIndex].Selected)
                        {
                            //doesn't work correctly for the moment when scrolling
                            bufferGraphics.FillRectangle(selectedBrush, rect);
                            bufferGraphics.DrawString(data.Date, traceFont, selectedStringBrush, xTime, y);
                            bufferGraphics.DrawString(data.LevelString, traceFont, selectedStringBrush, xLevel, y);
                            bufferGraphics.DrawString(data.Source, traceFont, selectedStringBrush, xSource, y);
                            if (data.Attachment != null)
                            {
                                bufferGraphics.DrawString("Attachment : ", traceFont, selectedStringBrush, xMessage, y);
                                bufferGraphics.DrawString(data.Message, traceFont, selectedStringBrush, xMessage + (xMessage / 5), y);
                            }
                            else
                                bufferGraphics.DrawString(data.Message, traceFont, selectedStringBrush, xMessage, y);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            bufferGraphics.DrawString(data.Date, traceFont, stringBrush, xTime, y);

                            // Info = 1, Warning = 2, Error = 3, Debug = 5, Special = 6
                            switch (data.LevelString)
                            {
                                case "Info":
                                    bufferGraphics.DrawString(data.LevelString, traceFont, brushInfo, xLevel, y);
                                    break;
                                case "Warning":
                                    bufferGraphics.DrawString(data.LevelString, traceFont, brushWarning, xLevel, y);
                                    break;
                                case "Error":
                                    bufferGraphics.DrawString(data.LevelString, traceFont, brushError, xLevel, y);
                                    break;
                                case "Debug":
                                    bufferGraphics.DrawString(data.LevelString, traceFont, brushDebug, xLevel, y);
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    break;
                            }
                            bufferGraphics.DrawString(data.Source, traceFont, stringBrush, xSource, y);

                            if (data.Attachment != null)
                            {
                                bufferGraphics.DrawString("Attachment : ", traceFont, brushAttachment, xMessage, y);
                                bufferGraphics.DrawString(data.Message, traceFont, stringBrush, xMessage + (xMessage / 5), y);
                            }
                            else
                                bufferGraphics.DrawString(data.Message, traceFont, stringBrush, xMessage, y);
                        }
                        bufferGraphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.LightGray, rect);
                        //
                        //                      if (data.selected)
                        //                      {
                        //                          Color color = Color.FromArgb(100, 0, 0, 255);
                        //                          Brush brush = new SolidBrush(color);
                        //                          _bufferGraphics.FillRectangle(brush, rect);
                        //                      }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (listLines.ElementAtOrDefault(listLines.Count - 1) != null)
                            listLines.RemoveAt(listLines.Count - 1);

                        if (listLinesVisible.ElementAtOrDefault(listLinesVisible.Count - 1) != null)
                            listLinesVisible.RemoveAt(listLinesVisible.Count - 1);

                        y -= 20;
                    }
                }
                else
                    bufferGraphics.FillRectangle(brushUnderTraces, rect);

                y += 20;
                traceIndex++;
            }
        }
        this.panelTraces.Invalidate();
```

Where bufferGraphics is my Graphics object.

Comment: What about `FillRectangle` at the start to fill the entire frame with the background color?

Comment: We need to see the code!!! Do you use e.Graphics as you need to?

Comment: I edited my post, you can see the code.

Comment: In the Paint Event I do :                 e.Graphics.DrawImageUnscaled(backBuffer, 0, 0); where backbuffer is my Bitmap object

Comment: So is bufferGraphics = e.Graphics? Also: Anything you add to a Bitmap will stay there until you overwrite it; there is no invalidating the bitmap other than clearing it. - Why even use a Bitmap since you are coding the Paint event??? (And vice versa)

Comment: I will try to erase Bitmap before rewrite on it. And I use code from another user of my company and it work fine, I have to update the code and I started from scratch because some components are differents

Comment: Well usually it is either Paint with e.Graphics or draw into a Bimap. The latter not in the Paint event but when the data have changed. For the former Invalidate when the data have changed. The only reason why one would combine the two is when a huge (>1k) number of draw actions are there; then one can cache the older ones in a bitmap and draw the rest over it.

Comment: @TaW Your reflection is interesting. Now you say it, I think my panel need to keep last draw (I have data generate every millisecondes). But I want to delete the draw I don't need.

Comment: Well, I wouild not draw more often than the human ey can see, let alone read. I was referring to situations like a drawing program. Maybe we should know a little more about the general setup..

Comment: At the beginning I used DataGridView but when data arrives DTG takes a lot of time to display data. So I implemented Paint and Data arrives very fast now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found the solution:
I used a method and I paint after. I set the body of my method in the Paint and it works fine. I replace bufferGraphics by e.Graphics.

Thanks to people who try to help me (my english is very bad so congratulations to understood me).